# Failed to parse single digit hour when the marker is PM - Java 8

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat, date-format

I am using the following code to parse a date:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy H:mm a");
df.setLenient(false)
```

Then the string `Feb 6, 2017 13:50 PM` matches but `Feb 6, 2017 3:50 PM` does not match (note that hour is a single digit). They both match if Iset the lenient option to `true` but I don't want to since the code will start accepting hours like 33:50.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3):

Using the "H" and "a" format options together is wrong. There is no such hour as "13:50 PM". If you're using a 24 hour notation ("H"), you cannot add AM/PM ("a") to it. Instead, you should use the twelve-hour notation "h":

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a");
// Here -------------------------------------------^
df.setLenient(false)
```

Answer (score 2):

Java 8+ Version:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter fmt = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy h:mm a");
// This will fail to parse: Invalid value for HourOfDay (valid values 0 - 23): 25
java.time.LocalDateTime.parse("Feb 6, 2017 13:50 PM", fmt)
// This will parse
java.time.LocalDateTime.parse("Feb 6, 2017 3:50 PM", fmt)
```

Comment: Uppercase `K` is for “hour-of-am-pm (0-11)”. Lowercase `h` for “ clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12)” would be more standard. Please also consider providing a locale (probably an English-speaking one; is AM/PM used elsewhere at all?) In any case thanks for providing a `java.time` version.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct, just a quick note: don't forget to set a `java.util.Locale`, because AM/PM strings are locale sensitive.

if you create your formatters without a specific locale, it uses the JVM's default. Most locales use uppercase AM/PM, so it works for most environments and configs, but if you want to make sure it works all the time, use a specific locale:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy h:mm a", Locale.US);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a", Locale.US);
```

That's because some locales use a different string (such as "a.m." for "es_US" locale, "fm" for swedish, "午前" for japanese and so on).